# Why is a member unique_ptr<> left non-null after std::move to a throwing function?

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, move-semantics, unique-ptr

When I move a `unique_ptr<>` into a function that throws, the moved-from pointer is left non-null. Is this the normal behavior?

Here's two test programs that show the behavior. I can observe the unique pointer in the destructor of the class:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::unique_ptr<int> &&) { throw "fail"; }
struct except_move_tester
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> x;
    except_move_tester()
      : x(std::make_unique<int>(0))
    {}
    ~except_move_tester() { std::cout << "x at destructor: " << x.get() << std::endl; }
    void g()
    {
        std::cout << "x at g: " << x.get() << std::endl;
        f(std::move(x));
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        except_move_tester t;
        t.g();
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

which when run gives the output:

```
x at g: 0x7f818b402ac0
x at destructor: 0x7f818b402ac0
```

If I modify the above listing as follows (just added a temporary at the site of the function call) I get the exception safe behavior I would normally expect:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::unique_ptr<int> &&) { throw "fail"; }
struct except_move_tester
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> x;
    except_move_tester()
      : x(std::make_unique<int>(0))
    {}
    ~except_move_tester() { std::cout << "x at destructor: " << x.get() << std::endl; }
    void g()
    {
        std::cout << "x at g: " << x.get() << std::endl;
        auto y = std::move(x);
        f(std::move(y));
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        except_move_tester t;
        t.g();
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

which when run gives the output:

```
x at g: 0x7f818b402ac0
x at destructor: 0x0
```

I've been moving unique_ptr's into functions under the assumption it was a sort of atomic exception safe operation, but this seems to indicate that an exception can leave a unique pointer in an unexpected state.

Comment: Try with `void f(std::unique_ptr<int>)` instead. `std::unique_ptr<int> &&` is just a reference.

Comment: The pointer has not been moved from.  `std::move` does not perform a move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) just converts the object to rvalue, but won't perform move operation.

(emphasis mine)

> `std::move` is used to **indicate that an object `t` may be "moved from"**, i.e. allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another object.
>
> In particular, `std::move` produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument t. It is exactly **equivalent to a `static_cast` to an rvalue reference type**.

Your 2nd snippet works because you *moved* `x` into `y` explicitly.

To fix the 1st snippet you can also perform the move operation explicitly, e.g.

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<int> && p) { 
    std::unique_ptr<int> t = std::move(p); // move-construct t from p
    throw "fail"; 
}
```

or just

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<int> p) { throw "fail"; }
```

For the latter, given `f(std::move(x));`, the parameter `p` is *moved from* the argument `x`.

Comment: agh, the exception was a red herring, from a bigger codebase. this makes sense. I'll accept once the time limit ends